# looping through recordset in stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have created a tbl having SELECT statement as value (fieldname sqltxt).

Now want to read rows one by one and execute all the select statement stored in this table.

If it does not return any row i.e. zero row

insert a new record in DMSResults with value of DOCID from DMSRec
For that I use following script

```
set nocount on
use TESTDB
declare @sqlTXT as varchar(max);
DECLARE @DocID nvarchar(30);
drop table DMSResults
CREATE TABLE DMSResults  (DOCID  nvarchar(30) );`
drop table DMSRec
```

`SELECT .....`**into**`DMSRec FROM tbl....`

Above syntax is a Big SQl script to create a recordset.
For my conveyance I insert all the records into new tbl.
Its returns more than 10,00,000 records
Now want to loop in tbl DMSREC, read the value of field sqltxt
Execute that statement.

If it doesn't return a record 
Insert a record in DMSResults with value of DOCID field.

I also tried with following commands, but do not know how to loop in sql for next rec until eof and exit

Since DMSRec is a temporary table, once a row is processed then we can remove record from DMSRec.

```
declare @rc as  bigint
Select @rc = Row_Count
From sys.dm_db_partition_stats
Where Object_Name(Object_Id) = 'DMSRec'

WHILE @rc <1 
      BEGIN 
      exec(select sqltxt from dmsrec where row=1)
--          here check record is exist or not then 
--          if it is not exist or returning zero 
--          add record in dmsresult with docid value
--          delete dmsrec where row=1  
--          loop for next 
      END
```

*Considering the huge size of database SQL-Server 2008r2 please guide me any optimize solution.*

DMSRec TBL recordset.

**DOCID**         **SQLTXT**

A01/17-18     SELECT VRNO FROM TBL_LET WHERE VRNO='A01/17-18'

Comment: your loop doesn't make sense... and may i ask why you stored statements in a table?

Comment: Basically I want to check some mismatch master & transaction records. for this I gather some values from different tables and create dynamically sql statement to check require record. After executing this SQL if there is no those records (value of DOCID).  Though I'm not technical I already wrote I stored that records for my conveyance. No problem if you guide without storing records into tbl.  If whole question is confusing, please let me know how to loop in sql and capture zero records result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't address the actual problem here, but I can elaborate on the question of how to loop through all records. BTW< loops are terrible for performance and thus are avoided at all costs in SQL Server.

```
--get the row count of the table
declare @rc as  bigint
Select @rc = (select count(*) from DMSRec)

--variables for incrementing rows and storing SQL
declare @i bigint = 1
declare @sql varchar(max)

WHILE @i <= @rc 
BEGIN 
    --get the SQL Statement from the table
    set @sql = (select sqltxt from dmsrec where row=@i)

    --If no value was returned, insert into DSMResults
    if (@sql is null) or (ltrim(rtrim(@sql)) = '')
    begin
        insert into DMSResults 
        select DOCID from dmsrec
    end
    --If a value was returned, execute that statement
    else
    begin
        exec(@sql)
    end
    --increment the row number
    set @i = @i + 1
END
```

Comment: `WHILE @nxt < @rc
      BEGIN 
           set @sql = (select Rec from dmsrec where row=@nxt)
           exec (@sql ) --with RESULT sets NONE;
           select @rc_child = @@ROWCOUNT;
           if @rc_child = 0
           begin
                insert into DMSResults 
                select DOCID from dmsrec where row=@nxt
           end
           set @nxt = @nxt + 1
      END`
I change according to my requirement, only how I can **hide displaying result of exec.**
I do above exercise is only for, if stored sql in @sql is returning any row or not so I use exec command.

Comment: Just remove the print statement